# Rmardown: Add horizontal scrollbar to avoid truncated output

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I am trying to print a large table in Rmarkdown and for some reason the output is split up which makes it hard to read.

I would like to add an horizontal scrollbar so it doesn't split. I managed to do it for the vertical axis, but not for the horizontal one.

Here is a sample of code:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.main-container {
    max-width: 800px !important;
}

pre {
  max-height: 800px !important;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
```

```{r}
mdl <- lm(data = iris, Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width*Petal.Length*Species)
summary(mdl)
```
````

This is how the output looks like:
[image]

As you can see, the horizontal scroll bar shows-up but the output is still split-up. I tried with both `overflow-x: scroll !important;` and `max-width: 500px !important;` without success.

The problem persists even if I set the `.main-container` CSS to `max-width: 1200px !important;` so that there should in principle be enough space for the model to print without splitting-up.

[image]

This is what I'm looking for:

[image]

---

**Update**
As suggested by @Rorschach, I have added the `options(width = 160)` to the script. This solves the issue in the second case, that is, when the `.main-container` CSS max-width is large enough (e.g. 800px):

[image]

However, if the max-width is not large enough (e.g. 600px) the print is still messed-up:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.main-container {
    max-width: 600px !important;
}

pre {
  max-height: 800px !important;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
```

```{r setup}
options(width = 160)
```

```{r}
mdl <- lm(data = iris, Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width*Petal.Length*Species)
summary(mdl)
```
````

[image]

Comment: adjust the print width with `options(width=160)`, the output is being truncated by R, not on the HTML side

Comment: @Rorschach Thanks for the answer, it solves part of the problem. Please see my update.

Comment: so it looks like a CSS issue now. You may want to tag it as such to get proper attention. Is your CSS being overridden by rmarkdown's perhaps?

Comment: I added the CSS tag. I'm not sure what is going on because the horizontal scroll-bar does show up, but for some reason the table is still truncated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an `css` expert but the following seems to do the trick:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.main-container {
    max-width: 600px !important;
}

pre {
  max-height: 800px !important;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
pre code {
  white-space: pre
}
```

```{r}
options(width=160)
mdl <- lm(data = iris, Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Length*Sepal.Width*Petal.Length*Species)
summary(mdl)
```
````

Comment: The problem persists if you set max-width to 600px (see the update)